# How to make a phone allow calling even if I haven't unlocked it since boot

Tags: lock-screens, calls

Is there any way to make an Android phone allow calling **arbitrary** numbers even if I don't unlock it on boot?

I have root privileges, if that helps. And yes I understand the security implications etc.

Comment: You'd need a framework like Xposed for that and to the best of my knowledge, there isn't such a module

Comment: Does your SIM card has a SIM PIN set? If yes you need to remove it because a locked SIM can not be used to do phone calls.

Comment: @Robert: No it doesn't.